# ASP.NET -> Adding a ButtonColumn to a DataTable or DataGridView (Programmatically)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having the odd problem figuring out how to add a ButtonColumn to a DataTable (or, arguably, the DataGrid). All I want to do is be able to use the data from the datatable to tell a button to do something onClick, and I seem to be failing at it.

A google search did not show anything immediately useful, as they are all using ItemTemplates.

```
//dt.Columns.Add("Ajax Link", typeof(Literal));
ButtonColumn newButtonColumn = new ButtonColumn();
newButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Asp.Net Link";
dt.Columns.Add(); // Doesn't want newButtonColumn.

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    /*
    Literal newAjaxLink = new Literal();
    newAjaxLink.Text = "Test";//"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"AjaxButton_onClick(" + dt.Rows[i]["UserInfoID"].ToString() + "); StoreUserInfoID(" + dt.Rows[i]["UserInfoID"].ToString() + "); ShowDiv();\">Ajax Link</button>";
    dt.Rows[i]["Ajax Link"] = newAjaxLink; // @todo: HTML button that triggers an AJAX call for load the proper data into the fields. Also to make the DIV visible.
    */

    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.ID = dt.Rows[i]["UserInfoID"].ToString(); 
    newButton.Text = "Asp.Net Link";
    newButton.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Link_Click);
    dt.Rows[i]["Asp.Net Link"] = newButton; //@todo: Just a button to open a new window with the proper ID.
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps adding it as a Field is the only way to go?

Answer (score 0):

**where are u adding the button to the respective thing?**...seems u r just giving values to button,but not adding.

Comment: This should be setting the reference: dt.Rows[i]["Asp.Net Link"] = newButton;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table"); 
DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
col.AllowDBNull = true;
```